# improving Container loading time using AWS ECS/EKS

Tags: docker, dockerfile, amazon-ecs, amazon-eks, aws-batch

we are running heavy ephemeral containers  it takes about 20 seconds to initialize the container and less than 10 seconds to complete the task , im wondering if there is option to manage number of standby containers that are ready to job processing and save the initializing time

we are using CMD  instruction to specify what component is to be run by teh image with arguments in the following form: CMD [“executable”, “param1”, “param2”…].

using @aws-batch

i want to be able to reduce the container loading time

Comment: Instead of launching a new container for each (fairly short-lived) job, can you have a long-lived worker process that runs pulls jobs off of a queue and executes them?  I might set up for example a worker Deployment that pulls tasks from a RabbitMQ StatefulSet, which could run in EKS without actually using any AWS-specific technology.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze , but how can manage scale up and scaledown ?

Comment: +20 seconds for an additional worker that will run for 15 minutes doesn't seem like unreasonable overhead to me.